# Girl lives underground with horrible people whose names all start with "W" or "U."

Tags: story-identification, books

It's a children's book. In the underground world, everyone's names start with the same letter and there is a king. I remember they were not nice people. She goes above ground and meets a boy, and they have to save the world by stopping and starting time. At the end she gets a new name, and it's "Mophy," or "Sophy," or something like that.

I read this in Australia as a child (around 2008). I remember the cover had a large clock/timepiece, and there were a lot of colours, including gold.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   When and where did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the cover/art?

Comment: If you remember any additional details, please [edit] them into your question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, while you're here (and as you're new to the site) please take the [tour] and look at the [help] Also as this is a [tag:story-identification] take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) on asking good story id questions.

Comment: "not nice" physically (as in mutants, morlocks, etc), psychologically (criminals, abusers, or just generally rude), or both?

Comment: A children's book like a picture book, a short chapter book, or something else?

Comment: not nice as in both mutants and criminals! and it was a children's book that was more for older children, and was a long chapter book.